# Get Table-name in insert statement by select statement

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get the table name in insert statement from another select statement in a single-line statement.
Example-

---

(TName) = select nameOfTables from TableRecords where uniqueId='xyz';
insert statement - insert into (TName) (ColumnName) values ('value');

---

So the statement should look like -
insert into (select nameOfTables from TableRecords where uniqueId='xyz') (ColumnName) values ('value')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those are two separate SQL statements.

You can -- however -- create a stored procedure that runs both SQL statements, and for you that will look like a single call.